# Extract firmware of an old electronic toy

Tags: microcontroller, components, datasheet, firmware

I'd like to extract the firmware of an old electronic toy.
Is has two electronic components, made by Texas Instruments:

- a PC35303NL - QB 8649, which is the main controller I guess
- TMP50C40AN2L - CM54157, which is the ROM I guess

A picture of the mother board can be found: [image: here].

I've searched the web for information about these parts but could only find a reseller who has some in stock. I could not find any datasheet.

Any idea on how can I make progress ?

Comment: Is that a "Spell and Speak"?

Comment: It's from late 1986. As the devices are probably mask programmed (and I think TMP50C40 is a MCU not just a ROM ... no. Google says it's a speech synthesiser) there won't be means to read the firmware short of milling the lid off and a microscope. You might find a TMP50C40 datasheet if you're lucky, and put a logic analyser on its connections to the other chip (mask programmed MCU)

Comment: Some days you're better off doing black-box reimplementation than trying to reverse-engineer something.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck it's a multiple choice game. There are paper cards with questions and answers. You place the card over the keyboard (a 6x7 buttons grid). You enter the card number and the game knows which buttons are mapped and can tell if you're right or wrong.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I indeed want to re-implement the logic which is trivial. But as there are more than two thousand questions, I would like to extract the knowledge from the game memory instead of answering them all by myself.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for your explanation. I understand that there is no read or write pin on the MCU to program it. I'm kind of stuck.